# Change the width of a ProgressBar added at runtime

Tags: android, layout, progress-bar, width

I am building up a UI from code and can successfully add ProgressBar widgets, however I cannot alter the dimensions of the widget to values I need, it always stays at the default size (around 50dp).  I've tried the following code;

```
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(activity, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
    progressBar.setMinimumHeight(20);
    progressBar.setMinimumWidth(100);
```

I've also tried setting the progressBar LayoutParams but again nothing and I've tried wrapping the widget in another layout, but still not luck.

Can anyone help, as I can't see how to do it?  If there is a solution using XML it could work, but I have to set the dimension and location at runtime.

---

For Progress XML I used the following.

```
<ProgressBar
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="10dp"
      android:indeterminateOnly="false"
      android:progressDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_horizontal"
      android:indeterminateDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal"
      android:maxWidth="1000dp"
   />
```

Then the code to inflate it is as follows.  This is a mix of what we have been discussing.

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_bar, null);
    progressBar.setMinimumHeight(10);
    progressBar.setMinimumWidth(200);
    progressBar.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 10);

    progressBar.setMax(100);
    progressBar.setProgress(getScrollBarValue());
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(isIndeterminate());
    progressBar.getLayoutParams().width = 200;
    progressBar.invalidate();
```

Comment: I guess a solution would be to copy the source code for the widget and to implement the missing methods.  Seems a crazy solution, there must be a way to do this.

Comment: Just to confirm: you are looking for the bar styles, not spinner styles? It would probably be enough to find out where the styles/shapes are defined and to copy and adjust them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

R.layout.activity includes this:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large.Inverse"
/>
```

And then the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);
    bar.getLayoutParams().height = 500;
    bar.invalidate();
}
```

The call to the invalidate() method is important as that is when the view is redrawn to take the changes into account. Although unintuitive, it does allow for better performance by batching changes.

Comment: I tried the method you suggested, but it didn't have any effect on the size.

Comment: I detailed two methods you need to use, calling one on its own won't work. I've just built a test activity using this code with a ProgressBar and it works fine. So I'd suggest you make sure that a) the code you've written is being executed, and b) that the code is making the size adjustment to the right progress bar. I've updated my answer to include the code.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try your code yet, but the layouts I'm defining completely in code.  So I create a RelativeLayout, then add a child view that is a ProgressBar.  setContentView is then used to add the RelativeLayout.  There is no layout.xml

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference, the XML is held in memory in exactly the same object, type, and structure, as if you create it in code. It's possible you are setting (or not setting) properties that are conflicting with the code that changes the size - try setting your properties exactly as in my example.

Comment: I see you added your code. Mine works and yours isn't yet, so I think you need to look at every difference between the two pieces of code and narrow down what exactly is conflicting. I notice you've set the layout_width to fill_parent - that certainly conflicts with you setting the width, as one will take precedence over the other.

Comment: I'm at work again now, so will have to try it tonight.  Will let you know.

Comment: I can confirm that this does NOT work - at least not with the bar styles on 2.1 - the spinner styles are sizeable, though. Besides that, the call to invalidate() is not required - which view do you want to invalidate in onCreate()?

Comment: @sstn The code above works for me in v2.2 using ProgressBar. The code is in onCreate() as an example only. For me the call to invalidate() is absolutely required, without it, no redraw occurs, and resizing does not happen.

Comment: Finally got it working.  I did it with a combination of a layout XML holding a LinearLayout with a ProgressBar child element.  I then inflated this at runtime and used progressBar.getLayoutParams().width=200 to get the width.  The invalidate call wasn't needed.  This was on a Nexus One running 2.2. I've still to test it on other platforms.  Thanks for all your help guys, it was your posts that got me there.

Answer (score 0):

There are minWidth/minHeight/maxWidth/maxHeight parameters as well, but (I think) they can only be set through XML or via a style/theme.

Otherwise, you could inflate your ProgressBar view from XML.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and I could get the height of the widget to change, but not the width.  From what I could tell the max and min width properties have to be the same for the size to take effect.  The max size property cannot be changed at runtime, it is not exposed.

Comment: Which direction is your ProgressBar? The size in the direction of the progress bar should be determined by the layout, usually.

Comment: This is not true, you can set the parameters in code, using  LayoutParams

Comment: @Ollie I meant the size will be derived/determined by the layout. Using XML or LayoutParams in the code will be the same, basically. Or did I misunderstood you?

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to define your own style for the progress bar:

```
<style name="SmallProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:minHeight">10dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">35dip</item>
</style>
```

Here, you can set min and max height and width of the progress bar and other cool features.

Now, you set in your xml layout style:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/custom_edit_text_progress_bar"
    style="@style/SmallProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

When you inflate your progress bar, you

```
getLayoutParams().height = 25
```

and

```
getLayoutParams().width = 25
```

for progress bar and set height and width.

NOTE:
You cannot exceed height and width that you defined in styles.