# How do I get a white circular progress bar in Android 2.2 and above?

Tags: android, colors, progress-bar

I am getting a black circular progress bar by default when I use the following code:

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background= "@drawable/login_screen_background">

  <ProgressBar android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/authonticateProgressBar"        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></ProgressBar>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/sigingInText" 
  android:layout_below="@+id/authonticateProgressBar"     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/signing_in_text"
  android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:background="@null"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
  android:textSize="17dp">
  </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I also tried adding

```
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"
```

but I am not getting a white circular progress bar. I have my background set to a black colored image.

Comment: if you are adding the progress bar at run-time..you refer this link.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008059/change-the-width-of-a-progressbar-added-at-runtime