# unable to change custom progressbar width in android

Tags: android

```
  ProgressBar progressBar=new ProgressBar(this,null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
    progressBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_bar)); 
    progressBar.setMinimumWidth(100);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302232/centering-progressbar-programmatically-in-android

Comment: i want to create progress bar same as VLC player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change it from Resources, from XML.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true" />
```

EDIT :

If you want to change it on runtime, take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008059/change-the-width-of-a-progressbar-added-at-runtime) link.

Comment: i created all code programaticaly

Comment: i want to create progress bar same as vlc player both end timer .

Comment: still not working its properly display on working but its width can't change. my progress bar is custom progress bar i change on that code. its not effect on output

Comment: Why don't you use it from XML. You can inflate that XML on the runtime and add it into your View as a child.

Comment: i want to create runtime dynamic Layout change on CountDowntimer