# Progress bar "removing" during loading

Tags: android, progress-bar

So what i want to accomplish is to "remove" parts of the progress bar during the loading. Look below for example

---------------- 100%

------------ 70%

------- 50%

--- 25%

Basically what i want is the text to follow as the progress bar goes down. Any suggestions how i would go about solving this?

Side-note: Anyone know how to make a progress bar look like this? (currently looking into custom progress bars, but haven't found anything like this yet)

-/-/-/-/-/-/-/ 100%

/-/-/-/-/-/-/- 100%

Basically it would be two different sections moving. Thanks :)

Comment: What medium? Ascii art?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm sorry? Currently I have the progress bar in a xml, however if this would only be possible by implementing it thru java, i could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you change the ProgressBar's width dinamically? And you set the TextView relative to the ProgressBar.

[Here's a code that might match your need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008059/change-the-width-of-a-progressbar-added-at-runtime)